# Checking user permissions in C++

Tags: c++, unix, permissions, directory, filesystems

I have some code to create a directory using the sys/stat.h header. However, when trying to create a directory that the user does not have the correct permissions for (such as a non-root user creating a folder in /), no error is thrown, and no output is given, even though the folder is not created. Is there a way to check if a user has the correct permissions before creating a directory? My code is below.

```
//Defines the mkdir command
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sys/stat.h>

//C headers
#include <cerrno>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdio>

//Custom headers
#include "string_algorithms.hpp"
#include "chdir.hpp"

//Defines current working directory
#define GetCurrentDir getcwd

using namespace std;

void mkdirFunc(string path)
{
    try
    {
        //Find how many directories need to be created
        vector<string> numberOfDirectories = strSplitter(path, "\\");
        int count=0;

        char cCurrentPath[FILENAME_MAX];
        if (!GetCurrentDir(cCurrentPath, sizeof(cCurrentPath)))
        {
            printf("ERROR: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        }

        for(int i=0; i<numberOfDirectories.size(); i++)
        {
            mkdir(string(numberOfDirectories[i]).c_str(), S_IRWXU | S_IRWXG | S_IROTH | S_IXOTH);
            chdirFunc(string(numberOfDirectories[i]));
        }
        chdirFunc(cCurrentPath);
    }
    catch(int e)
    {
        printf("ERROR: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    }
}
```

Comment: if(mkdir != 0)  perror()

Comment: Errors are given from the `mkdir()` function: Read the manual: http://linux.die.net/man/2/mkdir